# Extjs4 filtering combobox according to many values selected in a multiselect combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, filtering, multi-select

I have a combobox: `Problems`, I want to fiter the data displayed in this combobox according to aother values selected in another combobox: `Rooms`. But my problem is that the `Rooms` combobox is muti-select one. So I should applicate the filter according to many values selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

- After changing selection for Rooms, you have to reload the Problems store. In backend you should filter your output for Problems.
- You can filter your Problems store with [filterBy()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy)